# How to pass input parameter in stored procedure calling from single command line

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I know how to execute stored procedure by single command line

```
echo execute some_procedure | sqlplus username/password@databasename
```

But I am stuck how to pass IN parameter in procedure, actually My procedure taking two parameters.
I tried this but not working

```
echo execute some_procedure(123,234) | sqlplus username/password@databasename
```

It will be great if someone can help me on the same.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean - what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With what you've shown, you either need to escape the parentheses:

```
echo execute some_procedure\(123,234\) | sqlplus username/password@databasename
```

Or enclose your command in double-quotes:

```
echo "execute some_procedure(123,234)" | sqlplus username/password@databasename
```

Either will stop the shell trying to intepret the parathenses itself, which would give you an `'syntax error: '(' unexpected` or similar error. It's nothing to do with Oracle really, it's just how the shell interpreter works, before it gets as far as piping the echoed string to SQL*Plus.

Incidentally, I'd generally use a heredoc for this sort of thing, and avoid putting the credentials on the command line so they aren't visible via `ps`; for example:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<!EOF
connect username/password@databasename
execute some_procedure(123,234)
exit
!EOF
```