# Running SQL commands from within bash

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, passwords, sqlplus

Could someone give me example on how to run SQL query from within bash script. I've searched through Stack Overflow but couldn't find an answer that worked for me. I've made something like this before but for psql and it looked like this:

```
psql -U userName -c "SELECT * FROM table;"
```

The situation is like this, when I'm on my server I have to write these set of lines to select something from database:

```
    su - oracle;
   //insert password for oracle user
    sqlplus /nolog;
    connect / as sysdba
    SELECT * FROM table;
```

How should this look inside of bash script?

Thank you!

Comment: Which answers didn't work for you, and why? There are lots of examples using 'heredocs' for this sort of thing.

Comment: Basically everything I've found didn't have passing passwords and/or connecting as some user(connect / as sysdba) after getting to sqlplus..
I've found asnwers like these only: `sqlplus -s user/password@SID <<EOF
YOUR SQL QUERY;`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean still. Do you mean the `oracle` password, or the sys connection? Not sure if [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33829973/266304); or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816242/266304); or various others.

Comment: there's nothing to stop you passing usernames and passwords to sqlplus from a shell script except the wrath of your company's security officer, and you can also connect / as sysdba if you're running from an account that has privileges to do so (usually by being a member of the primary oracle group). I'll modify my answer with examples

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to do this. Everyone has a favourite, but they're all similar in that they allow SQL commands to be grouped together before being passed to the sqlplus command line shell. All methods are able to capture the response from the sqlplus to write to a logfile, and most methods support variable substitution, although some can fall foul of parameter expansion.

Personally I've always preferred the following method as it allows me to quickly make changes to SQL statements and keep old versions of the statements as comments. I know this can be done in the other examples but I just *personally* prefer this method:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 exec > >(tee logs/logfile.$$)
 exec 2>&

   {
     echo "TRUNCATE TABLE test_runs;"
     echo "INSERT INTO test_runs SELECT * FROM test_cases WHERE id = 6;"
#      echo "SELECT * FROM table1 where x = 1;"
      echo "SELECT * FROM table1 where x = 2;"
#      echo "UPDATE table2 SET status=$STATUS WHERE complete=1;"
      echo "exit;"
   } | sqlplus <connect string>
```

other methods make use of 'here documents':

```
#!/bin/bash
```

sqlplus  << EOF
    insert into table (field1,field2,field3) values('a', 'b', 'c');
    EOF

or use SQL statements held in separate files:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus <connect string> @query.sql
```

or take advantage of sqlplus's native functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus <connect string> -s 'SELECT parts FROM factory;' 
QUERY="SELECT parts FROM factory;"
sqlplus <connect string> -s $QUERY
```

Be wary of using bash variable with the last version, the following might not give you the result you are expecting:

```
#!/bin/bash
QUERY="select * from $TABLE1 WHERE url =\"Compu-Global-Hyper-Mega-Net.com\";"
sqlplus <connect string> -s $QUERY
```

EDIT:

example passing usernames and passwords from a shell script (security concerns that they're visible in the process table for anyone to see notwithstanding)

```
#!bin/bash

{
  echo "SELECT 1 from dual;"
} | sqlplus username/password@SID1
```

an old script of mine that connects as sysdba:

```
#!/bin/ksh

get_asm() {
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF  
connect / as sysdba
col path format a35
col CREATE_DATE format a20
set lines 132
set trims on
set tab off
set pages 2000
select inst_id, DISK_NUMBER, header_status, 
       state,path,TOTAL_MB,FREE_MB,
       to_char(CREATE_DATE,'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi') CREATE_DATE 
from gv\$asm_disk;
EOF
}

ASMDISK=$1
if [ ${ASMDISK}"x" == "x" ]; then
    get_asm;
else
    get_asm | egrep "INST_ID|^--|${ASMDISK}"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can feed the query to stdin of `sqlplus` using `echo`, for example:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM table;" | sqlplus -s user/password@host/DB
```

Answer (score 0):

## ! /bin/bash

```
...
MY_LOGIN="..."
MY_PASSWORD="..."
MY_SID="..."
sqlplus /nolog -s >file.log >error.log <<EOF
    CONNECT ${MY_LOGIN}/${MY_PASSWORD}@${MY_SID}
    ... your request ...
EOF
RET_CODE=$?
...
```

WARNING, never use this syntax:

```
sqlplus login/password@sid ...
```

with it, anybody who can use "ps" command could see all yours connection informations. Always use "/nolog".